# Running Sequelize Migration in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to figure out how I can run a Sequelize database migration with my docker compose set up and so far have failed with two different approaches. The first attempt I tried to run `npx sequelize db:migrate` in my Dockerfile after I installed the cli, but that failed I believe due to the fact that the database container was not running yet and then in the second I tried to create a container that depends on the database container and runs a command with the `wait-for-it.sh`, but that led to a failure with my `app` container reference. Both attempts failed, but I think I understand the logic that needs to happen.

- Build the container with the Docker file contents
- Launch the database container to have the database running
- Run the sequelize migration
- Launch the app server

Does this sound correct and does anyone know of a good approach?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:alpine
# Setting working directory. All the paths will be relative to WORKDIR
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Add bash to docker
RUN apk update && apk add bash
# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Install sequelize-cli for migrations
RUN npm install sequelize-cli --save
# Copying source files
COPY . .
# Copying shell script to ensure DB starts prior to server
COPY wait-for-it.sh .

# Run sequelize database migrations
# RUN npx sequelize db:migrate # FAILED ATTEMPT == ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

# Build app
RUN npm run build
# Port
EXPOSE 3000
# Run the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:alpine
    database:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
        volumes:
            - nextjs_auth_template:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
    app:
        image: nextjs-auth-boilerplate
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - database
        # command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "database:5432", "--", "node", "server.js"]
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment: 
            - REDIS_HOST=redis
            - DB_HOSTNAME=database
    # migration:
    #     image: app:latest # FAILED ATTEMPT == pull access denied for app
    #     command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "database:5432", "--", "npm", "run", "db:migrate"]
    #     depends_on:
    #         - database
volumes:
    nextjs_auth_template:
```

**.env:**

```
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=''
DB_DATABASE=nextjs_auth_template
DB_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
DB_URL=postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1/nextjs_auth_template
```

**package.json (npm run db:migrate):**

```
"db:migrate": "node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate",
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old but first of all you must change your sequelize config. It should be something similar to this.

```
development: {
  ...
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql',
},
```

also you should change it from your .env file. As far as I see, you are using redis, so your hostname should be redis.
Beside that you can run migratiosn in the docker-compose.yml like this.

Inside of your service, add this.

```
command: npx sequelize db:migrate && npm start
```